# How to create a list of files in shiny?

Tags: r, list, file, server, shiny

I am calling R script in Shiny. R script has a function that takes a list of files as an argument. But then read each file inside the function. Here is the example

```
folder <- "~/Desktop/shiny" 
file_list <- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.XLS") 


count_genes = function(file_list){
#Reading multiple files into a list of data frames, 
  my_data <- lapply(file_list, read.table)
.
.
.}
```

How can I create a similar list of (file_list) in shiny and render the result from count_genes.

The code is supposed to 1- choose multiple files in a directory. 2-apply the function on chosen files and 3- render the table.

Here's what I tried. Please excuse my indentation

```
source('ReadFiles.R', local = TRUE)
library(shiny)

ui = navbarPage(HTML("Title"),
                tabPanel(HTML("<font size=3>Start</font>"),
                         sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                                      fileInput('files', 'UPLOAD', multiple = TRUE, accept = c('.XLS')),
                         mainPanel(
                           tabsetPanel(
                             tabPanel("StaVst",
                                      fluidRow(column(6,dataTableOutput("tabel1"))))                                       
))
server = function(input, output, session) {
  lst1 <- eventReactive(input$files, {
    req(input$Load!=0)
    lst <- list()
    for(i in 1:length(input$files[,1])){
      lst[[i]] <-  input$files[[i, 'datapath']]
    }
    count_genes(lst)
  })
   output$tabel1 <- renderDataTable({
     req(!is.null(input$files) & input$Load!=0)
     lst1()
   })
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, this is your new attempt?

Comment: No it is not. It's a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fileInput` stores information about the selected files in a data frame. The data frame has the columns 'name', 'size', 'type' and 'datapath'. The files are internally copied with random path names (e.g. "...AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMxmB1G/48101199adb41c8ae7de0e78/3.txt") that can be access with `input$files$datapath`.

Instead of your for loop and your function `count_genes()` you can use: `tbl_list <- lapply(input$files$datapath, read.table, header=TRUE, sep=";")` directly to read each file in into the list 'tbl_list' or if you need the the file paths only you can use with your function `count_genes()`

Depending on your function `count_genes()` your object `lst1()` contains different things, i.e. the object that is returned in the function `count_genes()`. Using your function `count_genes()` as given in your question, `lst1()` is a list object, which cannot be handled by `renderDataTable`. To use `renderDataTable` you first need to convert your list into a data frame in the function `count_genes()`.

Here's a minimal example which may help:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("files", "Upload", multiple = TRUE, accept = c(".xls"))
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      # Output: Data file ----
      dataTableOutput("tbl_out")

    )

  )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  lst1 <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$files != "", "select files..."))

    if (is.null(input$files)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {

      path_list <- as.list(input$files$datapath)
      tbl_list <- lapply(input$files$datapath, read.table, header=TRUE, sep=";")

      df <- do.call(rbind, tbl_list)
      return(df)
    }
  })

  output$tbl_out <- renderDataTable({
    lst1()
  })

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do I need to use Ctr+A to select all files in directory? Is there an equivalent to list.files() in shiny?

Comment: The code above let you select a number of files with similar data structure. `list.files()`returns a list of files. `input$files` is a list with more than just the file path. Please clarify what you mean.

Answer (score -4):

I don't know if the following solution is acceptable to you, because it uses VBA/Excel, and not R, but you can consider it anyway.

```
Public fPath As String
Public IsSubFolder As Boolean
Public iRow As Long
Public FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Public SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder
Public FileItem As Scripting.File
Public IsFileTypeExists As Boolean



Public Sub ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)


    On Error Resume Next
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files


' display file properties
        Cells(iRow, 2).Formula = iRow - 13
        Cells(iRow, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name
        Cells(iRow, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path
        Cells(iRow, 5).Formula = Int(FileItem.Size / 1024)
        Cells(iRow, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type
        Cells(iRow, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified
        Cells(iRow, 8).Select
        Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        FileItem.Path, TextToDisplay:="Click Here to Open"

'Cells(iRow, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"

        iRow = iRow + 1 ' next row number
        Next FileItem

        If IncludeSubfolders Then
            For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
                ListFilesInFolder SubFolder, True
                Next SubFolder
            End If

            Set FileItem = Nothing
            Set SourceFolder = Nothing
            Set FSO = Nothing



        End Sub




        Public Sub ListFilesInFolderXtn(SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)


            On Error Resume Next
            Dim FileArray As Variant

            FileArray = Get_File_Type_Array

            For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files

                Call ReturnFileType(FileItem.Type, FileArray)

                If IsFileTypeExists = True Then

                    Cells(iRow, 2).Formula = iRow - 13
                    Cells(iRow, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name
                    Cells(iRow, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path
                    Cells(iRow, 5).Formula = Int(FileItem.Size / 1024)
                    Cells(iRow, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type
                    Cells(iRow, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified

                    Cells(iRow, 8).Select
                    Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
                    FileItem.Path, TextToDisplay:="Click Here to Open"

'Cells(iRow, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"

                    iRow = iRow + 1 ' next row number

                End If
                Next FileItem

                If IncludeSubfolders Then
                    For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
                        ListFilesInFolderXtn SubFolder, True
                        Next SubFolder
                    End If

                    Set FileItem = Nothing
                    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
                    Set FSO = Nothing



                End Sub



                Sub ResultSorting(xlSortOrder As String, sKey1 As String, sKey2 As String, sKey3 As String)
                    Range("C13").Select
                    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

                    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range(sKey1), Order1:=xlSortOrder, Key2:=Range(sKey2 _
                    ), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range(sKey3), Order3:=xlSortOrder, Header _
                    :=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom _
                    , DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:= _
                    xlSortNormal

                    Range("B14").Select
                End Sub


                Sub ClearResult()
                    If Range("B14") <> "" Then

                        Range("B14").Select
                        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
                        Range(Selection.Address).ClearContents
                    End If
                End Sub


                Public Function Get_File_Type_Array() As Variant

                    Dim i, j, TotalSelected As Integer
                    Dim arrList() As String
                    TotalSelected = 0
                    For i = 0 To Sheet1.ListBoxFileTypes.ListCount - 1
                        If Sheet1.ListBoxFileTypes.Selected(i) = True Then
                            TotalSelected = TotalSelected + 1
                        End If
                    Next

                    ReDim arrList(0 To TotalSelected - 1) As String
                    j = 0
                    i = 0
                    For i = 0 To Sheet1.ListBoxFileTypes.ListCount - 1

                        If Sheet1.ListBoxFileTypes.Selected(i) = True Then
                            arrList(j) = Left(Sheet1.ListBoxFileTypes.List(i), InStr(1, Sheet1.ListBoxFileTypes.List(i), "(") - 1)
                            j = j + 1
                        End If

                    Next

                    Get_File_Type_Array = arrList

                End Function


                Public Function ReturnFileType(fileType As String, FileArray As Variant) As Boolean

                    Dim i As Integer

                    IsFileTypeExists = False

                    For i = 1 To UBound(FileArray) + 1

                        If FileArray(i - 1) = fileType Then

                            IsFileTypeExists = True
                            Exit For

                        Else
                            IsFileTypeExists = False
                        End If

                    Next

                End Function



                Sub textfile(iSeperator As String)

                    Dim iRow, iCol
                    Dim iLine, f




                    ThisWorkbook.Activate
                    Range("B13").Select
                    TotalRowNumber = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Count - 12

                    If iSeperator <> "vbTab" Then

                        Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\File1.txt" For Output As #1
                        Print #1, ""
                        Close #1

                        Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\File1.txt" For Append As #1
                        For iRow = 13 To TotalRowNumber

                            iLine = ""

                            For iCol = 2 To 7

                                iLine = iLine & iSeperator & Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
                            Next
                            Print #1, iLine
                        Next
                        Close #1


                    Else

                        Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\File1.txt" For Output As #1
                        Print #1, ""
                        Close #1

                        Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\File1.txt" For Append As #1
                        For iRow = 13 To TotalRowNumber

                            iLine = ""

                            For iCol = 2 To 7

                                iLine = iLine & vbTab & Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
                            Next
                            Print #1, iLine
                        Next
                        Close #1

                    End If



                    f = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\File1.txt", vbMaximizedFocus)

'MsgBox "Your File is saved" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\File1.txt"

                End Sub





                Sub Export_to_excel()
                    On Error GoTo err



                    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
                    Dim xlWB As New Workbook

                    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
'xlWB.Add
                    xlApp.Visible = False


                    ThisWorkbook.Activate
                    Range("B13").Select
                    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

                    Selection.Copy

                    xlApp.Visible = True
                    xlWB.Activate
                    xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
                    xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                    xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Select
                    xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                    xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Select
                    Exit Sub
err:
                    MsgBox ("Error Occured while exporting. Try again")

                End Sub
```

The idea comes from here.

http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/

You can download a sample file form the URL.  Good luck.